# C++ Boost Graph Library - Dijkstra Example

Tags: c++, boost

I am having some problems with the code from [boost graph library Dijkstra example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/example/dijkstra-example-listS.cpp).  I changed it so that my version doesn't use enums and Letter rather just integers.  It complains about the for loop and the tie function, as well as other tie calls except for the first.

Declerations:

```
  typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;

  const int num_edges = num_edge;
  Edge edge_array[num_edges];
  int weights[num_edges];

  int size = 0;
  for(itora = edges.begin(); itora != edges.end(); ++itora){
    int u = *itora;
    ++itora;
    int v = *itora;
    ++itora;

    weights[size] = *itora;
    edge_array[size] = Edge(u,v);

    size++;
  }


  graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_iterator i, iend;
  #if defined(BOOST_MSVC) && BOOST_MSVC <= 1300
  graph_t g(vertices.size());
  property_map<graph_t, edge_weight_t>::type weightmap = get(edge_weight, g); 

  std::vector<vertex_descriptor> msvc_vertices;
  for (boost::tie(i, iend) = vertices(g); i != iend; ++i){
    msvc_vertices.push_back(*i);
  }

  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < num_edges; ++j) {
    edge_descriptor e; bool inserted;
    boost::tie(e, inserted) = add_edge(msvc_vertices[edge_array[j].first], 
                                       msvc_vertices[edge_array[j].second], g); 
    weightmap[e] = weights[j];
  }
```

Does not break:

```
for (boost::tie(i, iend) = vertices(g); i != iend; ++i){
  msvc_vertices.push_back(*i);
}
```

This part breaks:

```
graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_iterator xi, xiend;
for (boost::tie(xi, xiend) = vertices(g); xi != xiend; ++xi) {
  indexmap[*xi] = c;
  name[*xi] = '0' + c;
  c++;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
x.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
x.cc:141: error: no match for call to '(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) (main(int, char**)::graph_t&)'
gmake: *** [x.o] Error 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't really know what the error is complaining about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create a local variable `std::vector<int> vertices` somewhere in the unquoted code?

Comment: vertices is part of imported library, std::pair<vertex_iterator, vertex_iterator>

Comment: Do you know of anything else it can be?

Comment: @Jim: I stick with my original guess.  You seem to have changed the quoted code, and now I see `vertices.size()` which sure seems to support my theory.  You've shadowed the function `vertices()` with a variable `vertices` whose class (`std::vector`) does not implement `operator()` which is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: That makes more sense, if you had included that in your answer it would have made more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jim: I've never used the boost graph library and you did not quote enough code originally to support my guess with evidence.  I just asked the minimal clarifying question.  The answer to my question was "yes".  If you'd said, "Yes, but I don't see why that matters," I would have added more explanation.  Your comment seemed to say, "no."